# How to get focus back to cmd or terminal after filedialog or tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, focus, filedialog

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root=tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askdirectory()
test_str = input('Input for test: ')
```

Environment is Windows - cmd.
After filedialog, cmd doesn't get focus back to appopriate place - input() - after `Input for test:`.

Is this problem of Windows cmd?
Or just am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `root.destroy()` after `askdirectory()` line.

Comment: (Deleted answer, so that question is listed as unanswered. Moved comment here.) In Lubuntu 18.04 and python3.6.9 that I'm using, your code works as you want it to (I'm running it from the shell, with a command like `python3 ScriptFile.py`). Maybe it is a Windows issue, or an issue with how you are running it on Windows, I can't say.